# ReSharper 6 NUNIT

Tags: nunit, resharper

I'm trying to get NUNIT working with ReSharper, I'm using NUNIT version 2.5.10.11092.

When I run a test I get a windows dialog popup stating the assertion has failed, this is for a basic test.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MessageService
{
    [Test]
    public void BasicTest()
    {
        int number = 8;
        Debug.Assert(number== 9);
    }

}
```

Now the test did fail as intended but instead of having the test runner display the nice green red signals to suggest pass or fail I get this ugly stack trace popup, of which I can either ignore or abort.

I'd rather just use the built in ReShapper runner to display the outcome of the tests.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Debug.Assert` is part of the .NET Framework, not NUnit. Resharper doesn't know how to handle that. You should use NUnit assertions instead for "nice" output:

```cs
[Test]
public void BasicTest()
{
    int number = 8;
    Assert.AreEqual(9, number);
    //or
    Assert.That(number, Is.EqualTo(9));
}
```

There are different syntax assertions in NUnit. Which you use is up to you.

Comment: I'll give you the correct answer in 9 minuntes once it allows me to. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use Nunit assertions

```
Assert.AreEqual(9,number);
```